# Set global variable inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
var ww;
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
  ww = $(window).width();
});
console.log(ww);
```

I want to get the window width on resize and load, but variable `ww` is always undefined. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ?? You put your `console.log()` call *outside* the event handler. It will only run once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're binding a function to the 'resize' and 'load' events of the window, though you're trying to log the value of `ww` before either of those events have been fired.

Know that the `window.onload` event is only called once the entire page has been loaded and ready to be manipulated with Javascript. Doing anything before this event is fired means that you're executing it as soon as the script itself is loaded(when the script tag or file is reached), though any elements you might try to access might not themselves have been loaded.

Since neither of the events have been fired, `ww` will have no value since you don't initialize it to anything when you do `var ww;`.

What you need to do is log the value of `ww` inside the event handler, like this:

```
var ww;
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
    ww = $(window).width();
    console.log(ww);
});
```

This causes the event handler to be called once the page has loaded and also every time the page is resized, meaning that `ww` will be set to `$(window).width();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

You can access global variables using ***window***.

```
var ww;
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
  window.ww = $(window).width();
    console.log(window.ww);
});
```